# Kernel debugging in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, kernel, wdk, kernel-mode

I have a Kernel mode filter driver project. Host: Win8 Pro x64 running VS2012, Target:Win8 Pro x64 VM on the same machine. I was able to provision the VM through VS 2012 over the network. I deployed the package project. When I try to deploy and Install the package from VS, I am not able to succeed. So I manually installed the driver and the driver works fine. After installing the driver manually, I attach to the kernel of the VM and click on Break all. I find the Kd console in the immediate window of VS '12. I type the command "bu !DriverEntry" and then I type the "g" command. I see the message Debuggee is running. When I place break points on my code and press any key in the VM, I don't see the break points getting hit in my code. Need help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to debug through VS. I went for a work around and this time I used a Win7 VM. Made use of the KdPrint() method and used the DebugView tool to see the messages. This is a lengthy process but atleast I'm able to debug my driver. Hope this helps someone else too

Answer (score 0):

Use Fltmc command to load and attach your filter to a specific drive

You can put breakpoints directly in VS without the need to type in the console, if your filter is getting loaded after you type fltmc load "filter name" VS should stop at the driver entry function breakpoint, you may also need to attach it.

Dont forget to check if your debugger is working by when you click break all target machine should freeze.

Comment: The fltmc command has to by type thru VS?I'll try it and get back to you

Comment: You type in command prompt on the target machine with admin privilages

Comment: The fltmc command did not work. It gave me error Unable to load driver when I'm trying to load the driver from the same folder.

Comment: It doesnt matter from where you run it, it looks for drivers installed on your system. Not sure why you get that error, dont forget to run the command with admin righst and try using loading just the filter template with no aditional code.